# Problem with Non English(Farsi, …) subtitle

Tags: macos, video, language, subtitles

When I want see movie or video in mac os x (with [VLC](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.videolan.org%2Fvlc%2F&rct=j&q=vlc%20mac%20os%20x&ei=oECbTJ6JFpOj4QaVm9WAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHhAJ3QZ6KepVQi6V4S-8QzwYZeMA&sig2=mAhLDwDxy8lEGPwEdxzshg&cad=rja), [MplayerX](http://code.google.com/p/mplayerx/), DivX Player, Quick Time) and want to load subtitle these video player application can't load my subtitle correctly and show in strange text.

my subtitle languages is Farsi (rtl languages), and I must said I don't have this problem in windows.

[image]

---

I test many encoding with [MplayerX](http://code.google.com/p/mplayerx/) but still don't show it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the language encoding on VLC (and possibly others) is set to "default" which is windows-1252 (possibly only if your language is set to english, but I'm not sure)

This will not display other languages very well. To fix it, open up VLC preferences, click on the Subtitles and OSD tab, and change "default encoding" to UTF-8

This will give the program a much wider choice of characters to display from allowing it to render the characters as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, open up VLC preferences, click on the Subtitles and OSD tab, and change "default encoding" to arabic(windows-1256)...